# Self intersection of zero section of decomposable ruled surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, intersection-theory

Let $L_1, L_2$ be two line bundles over a curve $C$. Then we can consider the ruled surface $S=\Bbb P (L_1\oplus L_2)$ over $C$. Let $s_0$ and $s_\infty$ denote the zero section and the infinity section, respectively. In this case is there a way to express the self intersections of $s_0$ and $s_\infty$ by the degrees of $L_1$ and $L_2$?

Comment: The usual way this is written is to take one of the line bundles to be trivial. You can rewrite yours that way by first understanding that $\Bbb P(E)\cong\Bbb P(E\otimes L)$ for any line bundle $E$.

Comment: The degrees are $\pm (\deg(L_1) - \deg(L_2))$ and the sign depends on which section you are considering and what convention you follow.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I've seen the last statement in Hartshorne's book.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks. How can we show that the self intersections are $\pm (\deg(L_1)-\deg(L_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal bundle for a section is isomorphic to the restriction of the relative tangent bundle. The relative tangent bundle $\mathcal{T}$ fits into the relative Euler exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O} \to \pi^*(L_1 \oplus L_2) \otimes \mathcal{O}(1) \to \mathcal{T} \to 0,
$$
where $\pi$ is the projection and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the Grothendieck bundle. If you restrict this to the section, say, $C_1$ and use the fact that the pullback of $\mathcal(1)$ is, say, $L_1^\vee$, you obtain the exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O} \to (L_1 \oplus L_2) \otimes L_1^\vee \to \mathcal{T}\vert_{C_1} \to 0,
$$
and it follows that
$$
\mathcal{N}_{C_1/S} \cong \mathcal{T}\vert_{C_1} \cong L_2 \otimes L_1^\vee.
$$